# Parsing Date-and-Times from JavaScript to C#

Tags: c#, javascript

I have some JavaScript code that I'm trying to pass to my web service.  My JavaScript code is supposed to send a date in UTC format. Locally, the time that I generated my code at was at 12:30:43 pm. When I executed my JavaScript code, the following date/time was generated:

*2012-06-03T20:30:43.000Z*

That date/time was generated from this code:

```
var now = new Date();
var utcDate = new Date(
  now.getUTCFullYear(),
  now.getUTCMonth(),
  now.getUTCDate(),
  now.getUTCHours(),
  now.getUTCMinutes(),
  now.getUTCSeconds()
);
```

When I pass the date/time from JavaScript back to my web service, it is serialized as shown here:

*20120603163043*

That looks correct to me at this point. I then need to take that string and convert it to a date/time in C#. In an attempt to do that, I'm using the following C# code:

```
DateTime _value = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out _value)
```

When that happens, I get the following date/time. 
*6/3/2012 12:30:43 PM*

What am I doing wrong? I was expecting the date/time to be 6/3/2012 4:30:43 PM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result you get is correct, but please check the [`Kind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind.aspx) property of your `DateTime`. You'll notice it's not set to `UTC` but to `Local`.

You can use `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` to generate a `DateTime` with `Kind` set to `UTC`.

```
DateTime dateTime;
DateTime.TryParseExact(
    value,
    "yyyyMMddHHmmss",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal,
    out dateTime);
```

See it working on [ideone](http://ideone.com/K5xNZ).

Comment: I would think that using the [`o` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip) would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to serialize using (e.g. webAPI) I find JS `toISOString` very useful and compatible.

```
//JAVASCRIPT
var d = new Date();
$toPut.dateTime = d.toISOString();
$toPut.put()

//C#
[Put("/setup/dateTime"), HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage SetDateTime([FromBody]DateTime dateTimeSettings )
```

That way you can keep your data structure and not deal with parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass date parameter to web service as UTC format and then use TryParse method to convert it to C# date object.

Try this:

```
//Javascript
var now = new Date(); //just like: 'Thu, 21 Mar 2013 12:44:40 GMT'
var utcNowString = now.toUTCString(); //pass this parameter to your web service
```

And this is C# code:

```
DateTime date;
DateTime.TryParse(jsDateString, out date); //parsed as: '21.03.2013 14:44:40'
```

Hope this helps.