# how to store javascript date into sql server?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sql

I'm getting date from java script and want to store in sql table by executing c# code.

How to do?

java script format: Mon Oct 15 15:34:18 UTC+0530 2012

mssql format: 2012-10-15 16:18:04.000

Comment: how about storing it as a timestamp (long)? And then converting and rendering as needed by the UI.

Comment: do you think you are the first person on this planet solving this problem? :) have you tried searching? see [Javascript date to C# via Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1877788/944681) or [Parsing Date-and-Times from JavaScript to C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10872143/944681)

Comment: yes. i tried but not able to do

Answer (score 5):

You may parse the JavaScript date to C# `DateTime` type (using [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)) and then save it in SQL server using Parameterized query. For your date format you can try:

```
string str = "Mon Oct 15 15:34:18 UTC+0530 2012"; //your javascript date as string
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, 
                                  "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss UTCzzzzz yyyy", 
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: this is my code                                                    Dim time As String = DateTime.ParseExact(hdnTime.Value,
                                 "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss UTCzzzzz yyyy",
                                 InvariantCulture)                                                    but not able to store..its throwing error

Comment: @balaji, my answer is in C# , I have just divided the DateTime.Parse call to multiple lines for readability

Comment: my run time query                                                                          INSERT INTO payu_transactions(txn_id,txn_customerid,txn_amount,txn_datetime)VALUES('345785','30','656','15/10/2012 17:41:59')

Comment: getting this error  "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Comment: What is the data type of your Date column in Database ? is it `varchar` ?

Comment: I believe you are not using Parameterized query, Its better if you see: [Parametrized query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx)

Comment: @balaji don't concatenate the values; just pass the value down as a parameter. If you **ever** need to know what the date-format is on a database server, then you're doing it wrong™. Your SQL should look like `.... values(@id, @name, @date, ...)`