# JSON deserialize to class with missing key in json [string could be a single string or list string]

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

I have below class

```
    [Serializable]
    public class filters
    {
        public List<string> key1 { get; set; }
        public List<string> key2 { get; set; }
        public List<string> key3 { get; set; }
    }
```

and json string is

```
[{"key1": "key1value"}]
```

deserializing like

```
filters objFilter = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<filters>(json);
```

json string may contain key1, key2 and key3 or may not.

key1, key2, key3 may be a single string or array

So how can i deserialize it.

It is throwing an error mostly.

> class is not supported for deserialization of an array

Please advise
Thanks

Comment: To start with, use JSON.NET (Newtonsoft.json)

Comment: Why have you specified that key1, key2 and key3 are List<string> when the JSON you have supplied contains a single value? If it was a list the JSON should say `{ "key1": ["Keyval"] }`.

Comment: It may be a single string or list

Comment: If it can be either a string or an array, you need to declare it as an `object` then try casting to find out what was deserialized.  See [C# downcast the object type to map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989870/c-sharp-downcast-the-object-type-to-map).

Comment: Alternatively, you could switch to [tag:json.net] and use [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685).

Comment: Maybe you can also post the error you are getting that way we can see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is your json is incorrect

Take the following code in a console app and see what you get

```
var filtr = new filters { key1 = new List<string>() { "key1value" } };
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(filtr);
var text = "{\"key1\":[\"key1value\"]}";
filtr = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<filters>(text);
```

Or change your json just to the following

The '[]' in your json is a represenation that it it is an array, so you are trying to deserialize an array to type filters

```
{"key1":["key1value"]}
```

then your deserialize should work

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your JSON has properties whose values can either be strings or arrays of strings, like so:

> ```
> {
>     "key1": "key1value",
>     "key2": [
>       "key2value1",
>       "key2value2"
>     ]
> }
> ```

To parse this you have chosen to use [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is a very simple reflection-based serializer.  Its ability to customize the mapping between objects and JSON is limited.  Nevertheless you can write a [`JavaScriptConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your `filters` class that tests to see whether values of the `"keyX"` properties are single items or arrays, and deserialize appropriately:

```
[Serializable]
public class filters
{
    public List<string> key1 { get; set; }
    public List<string> key2 { get; set; }
    public List<string> key3 { get; set; }
}

class filtersConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        var filters = new filters();
        filters.key1 = serializer.FromSingleOrArray<string>(dictionary, "key1");
        filters.key2 = serializer.FromSingleOrArray<string>(dictionary, "key2");
        filters.key3 = serializer.FromSingleOrArray<string>(dictionary, "key3");
        return filters;
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        var filters = (filters)obj;
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        filters.key1.ToSingleOrArray(dictionary, "key1");
        filters.key2.ToSingleOrArray(dictionary, "key2");
        filters.key3.ToSingleOrArray(dictionary, "key3");
        return dictionary;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return new[] { typeof(filters) }; }
    }
}

public static class JavaScriptSerializerObjectExtensions
{
    public static void ToSingleOrArray<T>(this ICollection<T> list, IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, string key)
    {
        if (list == null || list.Count == 0)
            return;
        if (list.Count == 1)
            dictionary.Add(key, list.First());
        else
            dictionary.Add(key, list);
    }

    public static List<T> FromSingleOrArray<T>(this JavaScriptSerializer serializer, IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, string key)
    {
        object value;
        if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
            return null;
        return serializer.FromSingleOrArray<T>(value);
    }

    public static List<T> FromSingleOrArray<T>(this JavaScriptSerializer serializer, object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        if (value.IsJsonArray())
        {
            return value.AsJsonArray().Select(i => serializer.ConvertToType<T>(i)).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return new List<T> { serializer.ConvertToType<T>(value) };
        }
    }

    public static bool IsJsonArray(this object obj)
    {
        if (obj is string || obj is IDictionary)
            return false;
        return obj is IEnumerable;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<object> AsJsonArray(this object obj)
    {
        return (obj as IEnumerable).Cast<object>();
    }
}
```

Also, your root JSON container is an array rather than a object (i.e. the outer delimiters are `[]` not `{}`), so you need to deserialize it as a `List<filters>`.

Thus:

```
        var json = @"[{""key1"": ""key1value"", ""key2"": [""key2value""],""key3"": [""key3value1"", ""key3value2""]}]";

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] { new filtersConverter() });

        var filters = serializer.Deserialize<List<filters>>(json);

        var newJson = serializer.Serialize(filters);

        Console.WriteLine(newJson);
```

This outputs `[{"key1":"key1value","key2":"key2value","key3":["key3value1","key3value2"]}]` as desired.

Another option would be to switch to Json.NET, which has much more flexible tools for mapping objects to JSON.  See [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685) for specific instructions.